# How to validate beans.xml using a local XSD?

Tags: java, xsd, cdi, jboss-weld

In my application, I have some `beans.xml` files (for eeach module). each of these files contains required XSD declarations :

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd
          http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd">
```

Yesterday, due to some [JBoss.org outage](https://twitter.com/jbossorg/status/202754151308988416), schema files were unavailable, and as a consequence my beans.xml couldn't correctly validate.

It didn't prevent the project from validating, but slowed down project build (due to weld usage in tests, mainly).

So, what is a the solution, when using Weld 1.1.5 as CDI implementation, to not validate beans.xml during compilation, **or** to use a local XSD file (and if so, how to declare it, and where to put it in a maven project) ?

Answer (score 1):

Just spoke with Pete Muir. He said its a bug. Would you mind creating a JIRA ticket please?

Comment: Wait ... Can you elaborate a little on that (or put a ML archive link) ? You mean the bahviour of Weld validating on the web is not by design ? Cool for the future generations, but I have to use Weld 1.1.5 (I have very special requirements, and testing more modern versions led to various failures). So, is this bug t be corrected in previous versions ? I don't think so ... Anyway, where should I fill that bug ?

Comment: It's a bug that it's not using a local version of the xsd for validation. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/weld